# python working with acyclic graph

Tags: python, graph, dictionary, dijkstra

Well i have store into a dictionary a graph.The graph **has no cycles** and looks like:

```
G={1:[2,3,4],2:[1],3:[1],4:[1,5],5:[4]}
```

So in the above example node 1 is connected to node 2,3,4, node 2 is connectes to node 1 etc..
Note that any graph G is undirected!

Now, let's have one specific node and let's call them node K.
I want to make a dictionary to save for any node which is the path that connect this node and node K.

Also, i want to save in one dictionary for any node how many nodes have path connection to node K, and this path includes this node.

I believe for the first problem it's not necessary to run Dijkstra's algorithm because the graph is acyclic with no cost.

Any advice would be usefull,
Thx in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606018/python-path-between-two-nodes and . . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278481/list-of-all-paths-from-source-to-sink-in-directed-acyclic-graph

Comment: Duplicate after saying "use [`networkx`](http://networkx.github.io/)" ;)